# Network not working and bad archive mirror

Tags: networking

I am trying to create a liveUSB running Ubuntu server, and I am having trouble with my wireless adapter. I have a wireless adapter in place, and during boot, the server never asks me for my network, and just tries to auto config immediately. It never works. Always a DHCP error.

I try to skip it, but it gets stuck at  bad archive mirror. Help?